# Connecting Github account with Tower

Tags: git, github, git-tower

I'm setting up my Github account in Tower with 2 Factor Authentication. Everytime I try to connect the account, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred for resource /authorizations: Validation Failed
```

Can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Which second factor are you using? https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication/

Answer (score 5):

Please check your account page on Github.com to see if you have any Personal Access Tokens related to Tower. If you do, please delete them and try to connect again.